# Почему не работает роутинг в Angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, angular2

Я использую ссылку для роутинга между страницами Angular 2:

```
<a [routerLink]="/school/management" [routerLinkActive]="['is-active']">{{item.title | translate}}</a>
```

Где `/school/management` это путь, который описан в файле роутинга:

```
const routes: Routes = Route.withShell([
  { path: 'school/management', component: SchoolManagementComponent, data: { title: extract('SchoolManagement') } }
]);

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
```

Когда я перехожу по вышеприведенной ссылке - это подгружает новый темплайт в уже существующий, вместо того, чтобы заменить. В итоге по клику на ссылки у меня страницы append в существующую!

В нужном месте использую: `router-outlet`

Comment: как минимум сделай так `[routerLink]="/school/management"` => `routerLink="/school/management"`. А вообще `router-outlet` не в нужном месте используешь, другие варианты я думаю исключены

Comment: Проблема не в `routerLink` а в том что компонент рендериться как child в другом компоненте посмотри где находиться твой `router-outlet`

Comment: Возможно проблема и в `[routerLink]="/school/management"`, как сказал @Artsiom, потому что там `/school/management ` не строчка, а хз что))
Также возможно проблема и в не правильном создании самого `Routes`. Является `path: 'school/management'` дочерним к какому-нибудь роутингу?